# Samsung Smart TV Html5 App Sample (Real App)

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I'm looking for an real application for Samsung Smart Tv using html5 + javascript + plugins.

I found BrightCove and some examples on Samsung forum but they have only one page or are working with Scene.

I would like to know:

1) Ho to navigate between pages, parameters, etc;
2) What patterns and frameworks can be used;

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your first question, you have two choices:

- Using build-in Scenes mechanism ( http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00018/index.html ) [OR]
- Develop your own mechanism

While creating SmartTV app you need to look at it like on AJAX driven website. 100% of data transfer is done by asynchronous connections. Once main index.html file of the application is loaded at application start it remains not-reloaded until app exit.

So here are few steps to create your basic "scene" manager:

- Add AJAX library to the project (jQuery is best choice in my opinion)
- Prepare DIV container for data received from AJAX
- Prepare some kind of menu with onClick events handler
- Create kind of history stack (urls array) to handle "go back" functionality

There's a lot of other problems to develop:

- Remote control key handling
- Handling focuses navigation through active elements

And if you want do download data from remote server you need to remember about the cross-domain policy, so you'll need to set some headers on your remote server or use JSONP to jump over it.

I hope I gave you some light in the darkness ;)

Comment: Dobiatowski, first of all, thank you about your reply. I did this application using Scene mechanism but I wasn't happy, So I decided to change my project using html pages and redirects, but I found this problem, and I really don't understand why there is this option without documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using CAPH or Enyojs Framework to create app in smarttv
[CAPH](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/caph)

[Enyo](http://enyojs.com/)